# sort associative array in javascript by numeric index

Tags: javascript

I want to sort this array by the numerical index of schedules:

```
var data = [];
data["08:30"] = {data:"host name", program:"program name 2"}
data["06:00"] = {data:"host name", program:"program name 1"};
data["15:00"] = {data:"host name", program:"program name 3"};
```

I want to order this way:

```
data["06:00"] = {data:"host name", program:"program name 1"};
data["08:30"] = {data:"host name", program:"program name 2"};
data["15:00"] = {data:"host name", program:"program name 3"};
```

Comment: Using strings as indexes is sorted when `console.log()`'ed, and isnt using arrays for what they are meant to be used for. Thats why, with this example, data.length is 0. Since the Array class is extending the Object class, `data` is actually storing 3 objects with their names as "06:00", etc, not being an array

Comment: Associative arrays in JavaScript are actually objects `{ }`, not arrays `[ ]` https://www.codecademy.com/forum_questions/54f241b0e39efeb81000310b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I've been helpful

```js
var data = {};
data["08:30"] = {data:"host name", program:"program name 2"}
data["06:00"] = {data:"host name", program:"program name 1"};
data["15:00"] = {data:"host name", program:"program name 3"};

var order = {};
Object.keys(data).sort().forEach(function(key) {
  order[key] = data[key];
});

console.log(order);
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is:

```js
var data = [
{data:"host name", program:"program name 2"},
{data:"host name", program:"program name 1"},
{data:"host name", program:"program name 3"}
];

const sort = data => {
  return data.sort((schedule, schedule2) => 
  +(schedule.program.substring(schedule.program.length -1)) 
  - 
  +(schedule2.program.substring(schedule2.program.length -1)));
}

console.log(sort(data));
```